# Use of "einer" in the Genitive

Tags: pronoun, genitive

So I've written another sentence and would appreciate if someone helped me make sense of the pronoun "einer" and its inflection.

> Das Konzert fand während einer der heißesten Wochen des Jahres statt, aber da wir an dem See waren, war es okay.

Am I correct in my understanding that there has to be a chain of 3 genitives here: "einer" "der heißten Wochen" and "des Jahres"?

Comment: "einer" could equally well be the dative. Since this doesn't seem to be very formal writing, it is safe to assume that the author would ask "während wem," i.e. use the dative. An equivalent construction using the masculine where the difference is obvious would be "während einem der heißesten Tage des Jahres" with the dative, or "während eines der heißesten Tage des Jahres" with the genitive. The latter sounds more educated or formal.

Answer (score 4):

This is constructed just the same as English *during one of the hottest weeks of the year*.

That *einer* is genitive because the preposition *während* wants genitive. And the following genitives are because of the complements.